# Mockito spy an interface, mock it's default method, get NullPointerException

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

Suppose there are three interfaces like the following

```java
interface A {}

interface B {
  A getA();
}

interface C {

  B getB();

  default boolean foo(C c) {
    return c.getB().getA().equals(c.getB().getA());
  }

  default int bar(C c) {
    if (foo(c)) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to test the method `bar(C c)` with the following test

```java
@Test
void test() {
  C c = spy(C.class);
  C cc = mock(C.class);   
  when(c.foo(cc)).thenReturn(true);
  assertEquals(1, c.bar(cc));
}
```

but get a `NullPointerException` when stub the `foo` method.
The error message is like

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.C.foo
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:710)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

I'm quite confused what went wrong...

Comment: `spy()` is different then `mock()`. `spy()` does **not** create a *mock object* from your interface.  You have to create an implementation of that interface yourself when you want to use `spy()`.

Comment: exactly what the other answer said above. it's actually `Instance instance = new Instance(); Mockito.spy(instance)`

Comment: Spying an interface is allowed for testing default methods, according to [this PR](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/pull/942). I actually find out the reason of the `NullPointerException`. It is because I use `when(...).thenReturn(...)`, which will call the real method `foo` before calling `when`. I should use `doReturn(...).when(...)` when stub a method of a spy.